# DHCP Client Remote Access

Tags: vpn, dhcp, remote-access

I'm looking for a way to get Remote Desktop Access to my DHCP Client Laptops which doesn't have an internet access(This network is inside my office). 
Now, I'm trying to access a particular client outside my office(from home). 
I have added a topology to the existing connection. I'm using Softether VPN to obtain the IP Address but I'm not able to ping the DHCP IP or get remote access.

Kindly help me. I have given a diagram for better understanding:

[image: Network BreakDown]

Comment: Your question doesn't address a specific issue or a problem you are running into. Please review the help section on how to ask a good question: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have updated on the specific issue.

Comment: The issue here is I'm not able to ping the DHCP Client Computer over the internet, but local bridge shows the list of IP for DHCP Clients.